# Fabric - Test SSH connection to multiple hosts

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I have a Python script that uses fabric library to test SSH connection to multiple hosts. I want to gather all the results in one list:

```
...
import fabric
from fabric.api import *

results = []

@parallel
def test_connection():
  global results
  try:
    run('ls')
    results += "%s: SUCCESS" % env.host
  except Exception as e:
    results += "%s: FAILURE. Exception: %e" % (env.host, e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tasks.execute(test_connection)
    print results
```

When I execute the script, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_ssh.py", line 99, in <module>
    tasks.execute(test_connection)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 387, in execute
    multiprocessing
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 277, in _execute
    return task.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 174, in run
    return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "./test_ssh.py", line 96, in test_connection
    results += "%s: FAILURE. Exception: %e" % (env.host, e)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'results' referenced before assignment
```

I think it is because `test_connection` runs it's own context so it doesn't have access to `results`.

Is there another way I can gather my results then ?

Comment: You probably want to `append` to your`results`, not `+=`. `results += 'test'` results in `['t', 'e', 's', 't']`.

Comment: Maybe you should try it without the parallel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is that you can actually return results from `parallel` execution:

```
@parallel
def test_connection():
  try:
    run('ls')
    return True
  except Exception:
    return False
```

Now when you call your task, you will get:

```
result = execute(test_connection)
results = [ ('HOST %s succeeded' % key) if value else ('HOST %s failed' % key) for key, value in result.items() ]
```